# Javascript: Unshift to second position of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I understand this diagram:

[image: Unshift/Push diagram]

But now my question is... **How can I add an element just in the second position of the Array?**

If I have this array: **(A, C, G, T)** and I want to add **B**...

The result that I want should be: **(A, *B*, C, G, T)**

Any suggestions?

*Thank you!*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you want is the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function:

`arr.splice(index, 0, item);` will insert `item` into `arr` at the specified `index`.

Comment: excelent! this is what I was searching for. Thank you!

Comment: arr.splice(1, 0, 'B');